# Laravel query for hiding records on a boolean

Tags: laravel, if-statement, foreach, eloquent, laravel-blade

I am trying to write a query which lists all the products where `purchased = true`. If a product has the field `includes_bonus` set to true it should then hide the bonus product which has the id of `2` on the blade.

**use case:**

if `includes_bonus` is set to 1 on any of the product records always hide product with id of 2. If includes_bonus is 0 on all records always display product with id of 2.

**Current Query**

Below is the query i have created, the problem is when you turn off a product with `includes_bonus` set to true and then turn on the product with the id of 2 individually it hides that record.

```
$purchasedProducts = $user->products()->where('purchased', 1);
        if ($user->products()->where('includes_bonus', '=', 1)->first()) {
            $purchasedProducts->where('products.id', '!=', 2);
        }
        $purchasedProducts = $purchasedProducts->get();
```

**blade foreach**

I then plan to loop through each record and display it on the page

```
 @foreach($purchasedProducts as $purchasedProduct)
```

How do i modify this query to ensure the product id of 2 is always hidden when `includes_bonus` is true and when its false always show?

Comment: so if `includes_bonus` on any product in `$purchasedProducts` is 1, hide record 2 ... if `includes_bonus` isn't set to 1 on any then show the record?    you can just get all the records and then filter out the record 2 if needed

Comment: Yes thats what i need. I keep seeing filtering suggested but i have no idea how to apply it to my use case would you mind providing me with an example/answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could get all the records then see if they contain this particular condition, if so then get the Collection without the id 2:

```
$purchasedProducts = $user->products()->where('purchased', 1)->get();

if ($purchasedProducts->contains('includes_bonus', 1)) {
    $purchasedProducts = $purchasedProducts->except(2);
}
```

[Laravel 8.x Docs - Collections - Available Methods - `contains`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-contains)

[Laravel 8.x Docs - Eloquent Collections - Available Methods - `except`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-collections#method-except)

Comment: Cool, if i then pass the variable to the blade when i return my view at the bottom of  my function will it then take this statement into account? or would i need to modify how i pass it or change my foreach within the blade?

Comment: in the blade view you will have your collection that you can just iterate without any worry since you already altered it to your needs before the view

Comment: Okay, cool with `except` and the key param e.g `2` does except always point to a models id?

Comment: Because it is an `Eloquent\Collection` it has special methods that relate to things by the Model's `id`, so `except` is taking the id in this case ... but give it a go and see

Comment: Ah interesting thanks for the knowledge, Just tested this out its now all working! thankyou for all your help lagbox!